# Adding a number in a tuple

Tags: for-loop, tuples

I'm trying to add a number to a tuple but i get this error:

*"TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"*

here's my code:

v = tuple(int(input('enter a value: ')))

print(v)

what does this error mean? and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this error message: TypeError and the error message.

A TypeError is raised when a function is applied to an object of the wrong data type.They occur when you try to apply a function on a value of the wrong type.For instance, if you try to apply a mathematical function to a string, or call a value like a function which is not a function, a TypeError is raised.

The error message tells us that you have tried to iterate over an object that is not iterable. Iterable objects are items whose values you can access using a “for loop”(for example). An “‘int’ object is not iterable” error is raised when you try to iterate over an integer value.

To solve this error, make sure that you are iterating over an iterable rather than a number.

You have to convert tuple to list to add an element('number' in your case) and then append the number to the list.

```
tuple1 = ('q','w','35','70.00')
list1 = list(tuple1)
list1.append(input('enter a value : '))
tuple1= tuple(list1)
```

I have stated an example illustrating how we can append to list and then change it to tuple.